# Azure Backup requires ports?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-nsg, azure-backup-vault

I have created a DMZ subnet on Azure and have everything (inbound/outbound) locked down using NSGs. Currently I have a linux VM running and my azure backup is failing for the VM. I went and added Azure Backup service tag for both inbound and outbound rules but the backup are still failing.

Any thoughts on any specific ports or other servers I need to open up on the NSG?
I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure Backup makes use of port 443 (Https). **Azure Backup service tag** can also be used when backing up locked down VMs using MARS agent however the MARS agent can only be installed on Windows machines. So, backing up Linux Azure VMs with MARS agent is not supported as of now.

Comment: Thanks so my issue is i already have an inbound and outbound traffic opened for azure backup service tag but still fails. My VM is hosted in Azure so I am hoping to install the built in azure backup instead of using the MARS agent.

What source do I open port 443 to? is there a different microsoft service or IPs that I can whitelist instead of opening it to all the public?

Comment: Yes, you should be whitelisting the azure data center IP address ranges. Here is the IP address XML doc that you can refer to and whitelist the ports to these IP address rather than opening to public. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519